# Standard way of reporting user errors to user?

Tags: error-handling

I am writing an emacs package which provides some commands to the user. The user can run things like `M-x foobar` and `M-x eggsspam`. However, some of these commands can fail. As an example, without running `M-x foobar` once, `M-x spameggs` will make no sense and has to report an error.

What's the right way to signal such errors to the user? Should I use `(message...)` or `(user-error ...)` or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use whatever you think is most appropriate for your context. There is no "right" way for all contexts.

- `message` does not prevent continued processing of the current command. If you want to be sure the user sees the message, you can use `sit-for` or `sleep-for` (which see).
- You can pop up a window, frame, or tooltip with a message.  Like `message`, this does not, by itself, interrupt program execution.
- `user-error` raises an error that is intended to be for a pilot (user) error, rather than an error of the program itself.
- `error` raises an error that is (generally) intended for a programmatic error (e.g. division by zero, wrong number of arguments). In general, `error` is more general than `user-error`.
- `signal` is more general than `error`.

See the Elisp manual, node [Signaling Errors](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Signaling-Errors.html).  See also node [Error Debugging](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html), where you can learn some of the behavior differences between `user-error` and `error` (see option `debug-ignored-errors`).